# Why composition is so important in category theory?

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading ["Category: The Essence of Composition"](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/11/04/category-the-essence-of-composition/)

As a software developer, I understand why composition is important in programming. It's allows you to get complex components from simple components, helps to improve readability and maintainability of software.

But why composition is important in math? I did not find an answer to this question neither in the above article, nor in Wikipedia.

In other words - that would be impossible if the composition "disappear"?

I'm not a mathematician, so I would appreciate for the most simple answer.

Comment: Composition is simply the abstraction of "do this first, and them do that". It cannot dissapear.

Comment: I think it's worth noting also that morphisms in category theory "look like" composition, but can represent other associative binary operations instead (eg. group multiplication, poset comparison, etc.)

Comment: Not only does it abstract procedural idioms as Sr. Suárez-Alvarez mentions, but it naturally falls out of the behavior of the quantifiers of the underlying logic; if every person has a right hand, and every right hand has a thumb, then every person has a right thumb. It's an artifact of being able to instantiate universal quantifiers as arbitrary values.

Comment: The title doesn't fit to the question. Category theory is the theory of composition, more or less, and it doesn't make much sense to ask why composition is important for the theory of composition. The question asked here is: Why is composition important for mathematics in general.

Comment: Yes, I think, you are right. This is more correct formulation.

Comment: Thanks to all for explanations. I think, I should create new question: "Why is composition important for mathematics in general" (thank you, @MartinBrandenburg for your comment")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically, category theory was created to encode the functoriality of homology. Given a natural number $n$, to any topological space $X$, you can associate an abelian group denoted $\mathrm H_n(X)$ which gives you some kind of information on the space $X$. As such, it does not seems like an overwhelming construction. What matters in that construction is that to any continuous map $f \colon X \to Y$ you can associate a morphism of groups $\mathrm H_n(f) \colon \mathrm H_n(X) \to \mathrm H_n(Y)$ in such a way that
$$ \mathrm H_n(h\circ g) = \mathrm H_n(h) \circ \mathrm H_n(g)
\qquad \text{(whenever the composition makes sense)}.  $$
In a modern language, one would say that $\mathrm H_n$ is a functor $\mathsf{Top} \to \mathsf{Ab}$.
So, for the first categoricians (Eilenberg and MacLane if I remember correctly), **category theory is all about composition**.

---

Another answer to you question could be the following: category theory without composition already has a name and is well studied. It is called (reflexive directed) **graph theory**.
There actually is a way to categorically say that category theory is graph theory with composition, but you emphasize that you want a *simple* answer and it would lead us a little to far.

Comment: "Historically, category theory was created to encode the functoriality of homology." is not correct.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg It is clearly overly simplified to stay in the scope of the question, but it certainly enlightens the importance of composition at the beginning of category theory. For the sake of correctness, category theory was developped by Eilenberg and MacLane in [General theory of natural equivalences (1945)](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1945-058-00/S0002-9947-1945-0013131-6/S0002-9947-1945-0013131-6.pdf) ...

Comment: ...  in order to cope with the notion of "naturality" introduced in their precedent paper [Group extensions and homology (1942)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1968966?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) about homology of _groups_ (and not spaces).